# Reference a conversion operator through a \see command

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have troubles on referencing a conversion operator from another point in the source, this is a minimal example:

```
#include <string>

/*!
  Dummy struct
 */
struct A
{
    /*!
      Dummy operator.
     */
    void operator()() const {}

    /*!
      Dummy conversion operator.

      \return Nothing, really.
     */
    operator std::string() const { return std::string(); }
};

/*!
  Dummy function.

  \see A::operator()()
  \see A::operator std::string()
 */
void b()
{
    // Here I use A::operator() and A::operator std::string
    // so it would be nice to reference them in the docs.
}
```

The first `\see` command in `b()` function works, the result is a link to `A`'s
operator in HTML output, but the second one does not.

How do I reference a conversion operator?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, with a "useless" typedef so that doxygen recognises `string` as `A::string`

```
/*!
  Dummy struct
 */
struct A
{
    typedef std::string string;

    /*!
      Dummy conversion operator.

      \return Nothing, really.
     */
    operator string() const { return std::string(); }
};

/*!
  Dummy function.

  \see A::operator string()
 */
void b();
```

Comment: It works indeed but it is hardly satisfactory… I think this is a bug, I will report it to the author. Thanks anyway.